Building pybind11 example successfully, but still got ImportError
I'm trying to use pybind for the first time. I tried different ways, but eventually I decided to go with the 'official' PyBind11 example.
I did the following steps:

install Visual Studio Build Tools 2022 (I choose Desktop development with C++)
launch "x64 Native Tools Command Prompt for VS 2022"
navigate to the directory where I have the Python venv created
activate venv
clone cmake_example from PyBind11: git clone --recursive https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example.git
run: python ./cmake_example/setup.py install - finished successfully
run: python ./cmake_example/setup.py build finished successfully.

The last line printed by the script is: cmake_example.vcxproj -> D:\Git\pybindtest\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\cmake_example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd, so I believe everything is built successfully.
However, when trying to run  .\cmake_example\tests\test_basic.py, I'm getting a standard error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Git\pybindtest\cmake_example\tests\test_basic.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cmake_example as m
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit_cmake_example)

I got the same error when manually type import cmake_example in Python console.


Check CMakeLists.txt: Ensure your CMakeLists.txt includes the proper PyBind11 configuration:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(cmake_example)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED)

pybind11_add_module(cmake_example src/main.cpp)


Rebuild the Project: After confirming the CMakeLists.txt is correct, rebuild the project by running:
python setup.py build


Ensure Correct Python Version: Verify that the Python version used in your virtual environment matches the one used during the build process (python --version).

Check the Build Output: After rebuilding, check the output directory for the .pyd file (e.g., cmake_example.cp311-win_amd64.pyd) and make sure it's in your Python path (e.g., the same directory as the test script). Then run the test again.



Thanks a lot @Ishita! I finally got it working and your answer helped me! I was using CMakeLists.txt from the repo. After adding find_package(pybind11 REQUIRED) it stops building at all. I was confused as pybind is a submodule to the whole example, but I needed to set the following variable in CMakeLists: set(pybind11_DIR ./pybind11/build/lib/pybind11/share/cmake/pybind11) (this is a directory where I found pybind11Config.cmake file after manually building pybind submodule). Now it works! I wasn't able to install pybind using pip as I was getting some other error.
